# WordPress | Get term custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

If I have custom field on  **Term custom field** on **Term Theme**, its look like this:

```
<?php
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
$myimage = get_field('image', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);?>

<?php echo $myimage; ?>
```

I want to display "image" custom filed on Term posts, I mean any post who use term X get the "image" of X.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is **Term custom field**? What is **Term Theme**?  Are you trying to put a custom field on a taxonomy term?

Comment: I add new custom field using ACF plugin. look at my term: http://s22.postimg.org/ddqn6c7hb/test.png I want to display my "image" custom field value on my taxonomy-artist.php theme.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `custom-field` with the name of your custom field.

Like this 
`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'term-theme', true); ?>`

You can get more information from [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) WordPress codex page.

Comment: It does not work. But I aleady found the code for Term Page, I dont know how to display it on Single Post..

Comment: You need to edit different template for single post. I was going to tell you which, but is better to leave you find it yourself.